# Simpler way to parse XML

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have the following xml which is returning from an api:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <response>
   <error>
    <errorcode>1002</errorcode>
    <errortext>there is already an open session</errortext>
   </error>
</response>
```

I would like to read the error code. I write up the following code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(result1);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/response").ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText
```

Is there any other way of doing this by using linq or some other technique?

I am using an api to call as follows

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://api/access.mth?username=xyz&password=xyz@2021)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: *Simpler* to consume or *simpler* to write? the answer won't be the same. Using serialization as suggested by other will simplify the consumption of the code, but will be harder to implement. Which side would you like to simplify ? That said, you can simplify the code using this XPath : `xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/response/error/errorCode").InnerText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XML serializer which is located in the namespace System.Xml.Serialization. Create a class with a paramterless constructor that has public properties with getters and setters according to your XML elements:

```
public class response
{
   public error error {get;set;}
}

public class error
{
   public int errorcode {get;set;}
   public string errortext {get;set;}
}
```

Note: the parameterless constructor is created here implicitly by the compiler, because no constructor is defined at all.

You can load the file via

```
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.xml");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(response));
var result = (response)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
int errorCode = result.error.errorcode;
```

You have some flexibility regarding the format of the XML file. For example if you have also this file to parse:

```
<response>
<returncode>
   <code>100</code>
   <description>successful</description>
</returncode> <authkey>xxxx<authkey>
</response>
```

You can modify your class structure:

```
public class response
{
   public error error {get;set;}
   public returncode returncode {get;set;}
   public string authkey {get;set;}
}

public class error
{
   public int errorcode {get;set;}
   public string errortext {get;set;}
}

public class returncode
{
   public int code {get;set;}
   public string description {get;set;}
}
```

If you parse a file of first format, `returncode` and `authkey` will be null. If you parse a file of second format, `error` will be null.

Comment: Is it possible with out creating a class? because I have nearly 4 xml files of different data

Comment: Also when the response is success I will have xml as follows `<response>
<returncode>
<code>100</code>
<description>successful</description>
</returncode>
<authkey>xxxxauthkey>
</response>`

Comment: @Developer You might use a class for several xml files, see my updated answer.

Comment: OK but as the response is getting from an api when I am trying to load it to StreamReader I am getting an exception like `Illegal characters in path.`

Comment: If you have already a string in memory, try `StringReader` instead of `StreamReader`.

Comment: Hi let's say if I have a list which is returning from xml will it handel?

Comment: `<response><returncode></returncode><data><vessels><vessel><id></id><name></name></vessel></vessels></data></response>`

Comment: public class data {public List<vessel> vessels { get; set; }}